# npm run points to different .env file

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, package.json

We are working on `nodeJs/ExpressJs` we have configured multiple .env files for development and production and pointing it to `package.json` for different execution process, we have naming conversation issues at scripts.

Whenever we run `npm run prod` it takes to `preprod` configuration. what could be the issues?

**Update**: we have figured that the suffix of the script key is the same in the next script, after update/rename `preprod` to `preProd` the both runs fine. but why?

Eg :

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "clear; env-cmd -f ./config/hostedDev.env nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "prod": "clear; env-cmd -f ./config/prod.env nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "preprod": "clear; env-cmd -f ./config/preprod.env nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Can you create a simpler reproducible example. Like just "echo something" (instead of "nodemon") just to confirm what you're saying is really happening.

Comment: Using [different .env files in an anti-pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files). Different environments (dev/prod) should have their own ".env" files (same filename).

Comment: @laggingreflex, It does indeed, I tried using `echo`. Apparently its something to do specifically with 'preprod', script executes correctly using 'preProd' even 'prrprod' (just one char change).

Comment: Also to note is it runs both scripts when we run `npm run prod` i.e It executes both preprod and prod respectively.

Comment: @151291 Please approve/upvote if you found the answer useful! :)

Comment: `@151291` -  Changing the script name from `preprod` to `preProd` (as you've said) will run successfully. However, if you were to then subsequently rename the `prod` script  to `Prod` you'll encounter the same issue again. This is because of npm's built-in [pre- and post- hooks](https://medium.com/yld-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf) feature. For instance lets say you have an npm script named `foo` and another npm script named `prefoo` - when you run `npm run foo` via your CLI the `prefoo` script will auto run before `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the issue is with the word 'pre'.
If you would have noticed it runs both preprod and prod commands (pre running first).
If you change the script name to 'postprod' the postprod script will run later.

So, I guess npm uses 'pre' as to run before the 'prod' script and then running 'prod' script itself.